# Почему при вызове функции из словаря получается None?

Tags: python, python-3.x, функции

```
import simple_draw as sd

sd.resolution = (800, 900)


print('Список доступных фигур')
figure_dict = {
    1: 'треугольник',
    2: 'квадрат',
    3: 'пятиугольник',
    4: 'шестиугольник'
}

for code_figure in figure_dict:
    print(code_figure, ':', figure_dict[code_figure])

user_input = input("Введите, номер желаемой фигуры: ")
code_figure = int(user_input)
if code_figure < 1 or code_figure > 4:
    print('Вы ввели некоректный номер')
print('Вы ввели', code_figure, ' : ', figure_dict[code_figure])

point_0 = sd.get_point(220, 350)
point_1 = sd.get_point(220, 350)
point_2 = sd.get_point(220, 350)
point_3 = sd.get_point(220, 350)


def drawing_figure(point, angle, length, step):
    v = sd.get_vector(start_point=point, angle=angle, length=length, width=4)
    for angle in range(0, 360, step):
        v = sd.get_vector(start_point=v.end_point, angle=angle, length=length, width=4)
        v.draw()


def triangle(point, angle, length, side):
    step = 360 // side
    drawing_figure(point, angle, length, step)


def square(point, angle, length, side):
    step = 360 // side
    drawing_figure(point, angle, length, step)


def pentagon(point, angle, length, side):
    step = 360 // side
    drawing_figure(point, angle, length, step)


def hexagon(point, angle, length, side):
    step = 360 // side
    drawing_figure(point, angle, length, step)


drawing_figure_dict = {
    1: triangle(point=point_0, angle=0, length=120, side=3),
    2: square(point=point_1, angle=0, length=120, side=4),
    3: pentagon(point=point_2, angle=0, length=120, side=5),
    4: hexagon(point=point_3, angle=0, length=120, side=6)
}

for drawing_code_figure in drawing_figure_dict:
    print(drawing_code_figure, ':', drawing_figure_dict[drawing_code_figure])
drawing_code_figure = int(user_input)
print('Вы ввели', drawing_code_figure, ' : ', drawing_figure_dict[drawing_code_figure])


sd.pause()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас ни в одной функции нет return.

Если из функции не возвращается явно результат, то результатом её выполнения считается пустое значение, то есть None.

Таким образом, этот словарь:

```
drawing_figure_dict = {
    1: triangle(point=point_0, angle=0, length=120, side=3),
    2: square(point=point_1, angle=0, length=120, side=4),
    3: pentagon(point=point_2, angle=0, length=120, side=5),
    4: hexagon(point=point_3, angle=0, length=120, side=6)
}
```

после вычисления значений функций будет выглядеть так:

```
drawing_figure_dict = {
    1: None,
    2: None,
    3: None,
    4: None
}
```

UPD: Ваша проблема в том, что ваши функции в словаре вызываются сразу же в момент создания словаря. Нужно как-то сделать, чтобы они не вызывались сразу, а только после выбора пользователя вызывалась бы одна из них.

По-хорошему, половину кода вообще стоило бы переписать по-другому. Но можно просто обернуть функции в лямбды - это предотвратит их срабатывание сразу. И уже после выбора пользователя дёрнуть нужную лямбду.

Словарь будет выглядеть вот так:

```
drawing_figure_dict = {
    1: lambda: triangle(point=point_0, angle=0, length=120, side=3),
    2: lambda: square(point=point_1, angle=0, length=120, side=4),
    3: lambda: pentagon(point=point_2, angle=0, length=120, side=5),
    4: lambda: hexagon(point=point_3, angle=0, length=120, side=6)
}
```

А после выбора пользователя нужно сделать вот так:

```
drawing_figure_dict[drawing_code_figure]()
```

Comment: вставил return получаю RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object

Comment: @Радик, покажите ту версию кода, на которой вы получаете эту ошибку. Или вы ожидаете, что я догадаюсь, куда и как вы вставили return?

Comment: def triangle(point, angle, length, side):
    step = 360 // side
    drawing_figure(point, angle, length, step)
    return triangle(point, angle, length, side)
def square(point, angle, length, side):
    step = 360 // side
    drawing_figure(point, angle, length, step)
    return square(point, angle, length, side)

Comment: добавил только в конце функций фигур  return  имя_функции(point, angle, length, side)

Comment: Ну так конечно ошибка будет. Вы внутри функции вызываете её же саму, и при этом вызове она опять же вызывает себя, и так до бесконечности. Какого вывод на экран вы вообще хотите получить?

Comment: что возвращать из функции в данном случае?

Comment: Ну так а что вы хотите-то вывести на экран? Опишите желаемое поведение кода.

Comment: в данном случае я хочу получить одну фигуру когда при запуске комманды введите фигуру  от 1 до 4  отрисовываем соответсвующую фигуру по ключу словаря.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85602/discussion-between--and-).